# Different unique validation depending on the route name

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-9, laravel-10

I have two *different* routes of type **GET** pointing to the *same* route of type **POST**.

I would like to have a validation, in this specific case, a unique one described as follows:

This is the first GET type route:

`Route::get('/createproject', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@create');`

This is the second GET type route:

`Route::get('/duplicateproject', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@duplicate');`

This is the POST type route:

`Route::post('/projects', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@store');`

The first unique referring to the first route of type GET:

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:projects,title',
]);
```

The second unique referring to the second route of type GET:

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:projects,title,'.$project->id,
]);
```

All this in a single validation.

Is it possible to do this? Can you kindly help me? Thanks to all

Comment: `'required|unique:projects,title,' . ($project ? $project->id : null),` could work (only include the `id` to ignore if present), or look at the alternative syntax for Validation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique, like `'title' => ['required', $project ? Rule::unique('projects', 'title') : Rule::unique('projects', 'title') ->ignore($project->id)]`, or similar)

Comment: @TimLewis Can you explain me better please? Even with an answer if you can. I'm a newbie to Laravel

Comment: I couldn't post an answer, as it kinda depends on your Controller, i.e if you're doing this with a `FormRequest`, or a Manual Validator, which you didn't include in your question. But look at the `unique:...` syntax; the 3rd parameter is an `id` to ignore, which in your case is only present some times, so only include that 3rd parameter if you need it, via `. ($project ? $project->id : null)`. The `Rule::unique()` syntax is just a different way to write that rule, which might make it easier to understand.

Comment: @TimLewis it is simply a Manual Validator